# How do I achieve the "Find My Friends" button look using iOS 5? it is as if the buttons are stamped into the leather

Tags: ios, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

How do I achieve the "Find My Friends" button look using iOS 5? it is as if the buttons are stamped into the leather.

I like the look of the Find My Friends app, it looks like leather and the buttons look like they are stamped into the leather. So, I was wondering how do I achieve this stamped in effect. I know how to set the background image in iOS 5 on a UINavigationBar, and I can set the tint color of a UIBarButton.

But, how do I get the image on the UINavigationBar to bleed through to the UIBarButton?

Everything I've tried leads to a black button and no bleeding of the background image.

I was thinking that there must be a way to set the transparency of the UIBarButton.

Does anyone know if this possible in iOS 5?

Or, do I need to do this?
Create a custom button image that is in the shape of the button image : rounded corners , 3D button effect and a transparent color in the middle.
This way the leather will show through where it is transparent in the middle of the button.

Thanks in advance! Brian.

Answer (score 1):

Get your artist to draw the stamped button for you. The system is not going to offer any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you'll need to go with building a custom button image that has a translucent background colour for the leather to show through.

As you've mentioned, you can set the `tintColor` property on UIBarButtonItem, but this doesn't seem to respect the alpha of the colour you set.  The image seems the best way to go.